# Is there a way to get Record fields by string in F#?

Tags: f#

I would like to get the value of a field in a Record by looking it up with a string.

```
type Test = { example : string  }
let test = { example = "this is the value" }
let getByName (s:string) =
  ???? //something like test.GetByName(s)
```

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't as it requires reflection, circumventing the standard, clean part of the type system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard [.net reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) should be working fine for such scenario. Record fields are exposed as properties, so you can just query the type with reflection API.
It could look like this:

```
  let getByName (s:string) =
    match typeof<Test>.GetProperties() |> Array.tryFind (fun t -> t.Name = s)
      with
      | Some pi -> Some(pi.GetValue(test))
      | None -> None
```

Comment: Just a small optimization by using library functions:
``let getByName s = typeof<Test>.GetProperties () |> Array.tryFind (fun t -> t.Name = s) |> Option.map (fun pi -> pi.GetValue test)``

Comment: A safer way is to use `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType.GetRecordFields`. That will *only* return the record fields, while `GetProperties()` could return user-defined properties that are defined on the type (like `member this.X = 42`).